# JQuery POSTing data after getting the response

Tags: jquery

I have some code, posting data from "my_form" to server with JQuery $post every 3 seconds.
Everything works fine, but sometimes maybe because of slow Internet connection the response doesn't come in 3 seconds, when cycle triggers.
This makes an error. Of course, I can increase the delay from 3 seconds to 6 and more, but it slows down the process. 
How can I change the code to post data only after getting the response?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#my_form").submit(function() {
        document.forms["my_form"]["submit"].disabled="true";
        counter=0;
        var post_data = function() {
            $.post("formProcessor.php", $("#my_form").serialize(),
            function(data) {
                $("#formResponse").html(data);
                txt = $("#formResponse").text();
                ...
                //some code analyzing response 
                ...
                if (counter == 50){
                    clearInterval(nre);
                    return false;
                };
                changeFields(counter);
            }
        );
    };
    var nre=setInterval(post_data,3000);
    return false;
});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like in code below. Pretty simple. Just additional variable `requestFinished` which is set to true if request is done .

```
    var requestFinished = true;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#my_form").submit(function() {
        document.forms["my_form"]["submit"].disabled="true";
        counter=0;
        var post_data = function() {
            if(requestFinished) {
                requestFinished = false;
                $.post("formProcessor.php", $("#my_form").serialize(),
                    function(data) {
                        requestFinished = true;
                        $("#formResponse").html(data);
                        txt = $("#formResponse").text();
                        ...
                        //some code analyzing response 
                        ...
                        if (counter == 50){
                            clearInterval(nre);
                            return false;
                        };
                        changeFields(counter);
                    }
                );
            }
    };
    var nre=setInterval(post_data,3000);
    return false;
});
});
```

Comment: Yes, it works! Now I can experiment with interval to increase the speed of posting data. Thank You.